# In Tabulator.js, how can I set the value of a cell to a string that contains angle brackets? e.g. "a<b<c"

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a cell in my Tabulator table that uses a list type editor. The options are populated by an array of strings that looks like (as an example):

```
   [
   "a<b",
   "b<c",
   "c<d",
   ]
```

When the list editor is populated (using editorParams:{values:exampleOptions} in the column definition), or when I use setValue() on the cell directly, it drops everything after the angle bracket. So I see something like this in the dropdown list:

```
   "a",
   "b",
   "c",
```

How can I get the full string into that dropdown list/cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing `"<"` with `"&lt;"`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `itemFormatter` option in `editorParams` to define a new element node for the values list, and return the `innerHTML` of the element containing the list value:

```
editorParams: {
  values: ["a<b", "b<c", "c<d"],
  itemFormatter: (label, value, item, element) => {
    const listNode = document.createTextNode(value);
    element.appendChild(listNode);

    return element.innerHTML;
  }
},
```

Here is an example on the `name` column:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Billy Bob',
    age: '12',
    gender: 'male',
    height: 1,
    col: 'red',
    dob: '',
    cheese: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mary May',
    age: '1',
    gender: 'female',
    height: 2,
    col: 'blue',
    dob: '14/05/1982',
    cheese: true
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Margret Marmajuke',
    age: '16',
    gender: 'female',
    height: 5,
    col: 'yellow',
    dob: '31/01/1999'
  }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [{
      title: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      editor: "list",
      editorParams: {
        values: ["a<b", "b<c", "c<d"],
        itemFormatter: (label, value, item, element) => {
          const listNode = document.createTextNode(value);
          element.appendChild(listNode);

          return element.innerHTML;
        }
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      field: 'age'
    },
    {
      title: 'Gender',
      field: 'gender'
    },
    {
      title: 'Height',
      field: 'height'
    },
    {
      title: 'Favourite Color',
      field: 'col'
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, that made the dropdown list in the tabulator column show the correct value but when I actually select it, it drops everything after the "<" still

Comment: The example I included above doesn't seem to drop anything after the `<` but you may have a different use case. Glad you got it working!